# Is it possible to release something with proprietary dependencies under Apache2 licence?

Tags: licensing, open-source, apache-license

If I write code with proprietary dependencies, can I release my own code under the Apache licence?

An example of this would be a plugin for a proprietary framework.

Comment: I don't know the terms by heart, but can you release for example a Windows application under the Apache license (i.e. an open/free application that runs on a proprietary OS)?

Comment: Haha good point :-)

Comment: Can you put more details of the license of the proprietary dependencies you are referring to? Also can you tell us whether you are subject to distributing the proprietary dependency or if the user of yours can directly acquire dependencies? Can you elaborate more.